# Pass value from function to another one without overwriting it

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, bind

I have an image, I'm trying to let the user chose the proper rgb values for its desired function. So the user is allowed to click on the image in the desired area and than he presses a button to save that clicked value.

I have the following code where the function click gets the color value and stores it in an array, another function **yellow_calib** is supposed to save the last clicked color in an array. Except that when the **yellow_calib** is called, it gets the buttons colour and not the last clicked pixel in image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from ctypes import windll

#frameWidth = 800
#frameHeight = 600
path="C:/Users/PC/Desktop/M2/venv/paperEval.png"

# reading the image
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

#Rearrang the color channel
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))

root = tk.Tk()

im = Image.fromarray(img)
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)

selected_color = np.empty([0,3]) #color to be passed to the button
def click(event):
    global selected_color
    dc = windll.user32.GetDC(0)
    rgb = windll.gdi32.GetPixel(dc,event.x_root,event.y_root)
    r = rgb & 0xff
    g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff
    b = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff
    selected_color = [r,g,b] #saving the clicked color
    print("Clicked color : ", selected_color)

# Put it in the display window
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame = tk.Label(root, image=imgtk)
frame.pack(side = tk.TOP)

root.bind('<Button-1>', click)

#Frame for colors
RightFrame = tk.Frame(root)
RightFrame.pack(side = tk.BOTTOM)

#Definition of functions to save color
AllColors = np.empty([6,3], dtype=int)
#print(AllColors)
def yellow_calib():
    AllColors[0,] = selected_color #past the last value saved ?
    print("Yellow color : ", AllColors[0,]) #print the Yellow value

#Yellow BUTTON
YellowButton = tk.Button(RightFrame, text ="Calib Yellow")
YellowButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

This code gives me the following output :

[image]

So when I click on the image, I got the the array **clicked image : [128,87,105]** and when I click on the yellow button, it gets **[135, 206, 240]** and I want it to get **[128,87,105]**.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I did not get exactly what you are trying to do. And what "pass value without overwriting" means.

But I suspect that your real problem is here:

```py
selected_color = np.empty([0,3]) #color to be passed to the button
def click(event):
    # yada yada yada...
    selected_color = [r,g,b] #saving the clicked color
```

In this code `selected_color` is a local variable. You are "saving" it just before the end of the `click` function. So just before that variable is destroyed anyway.
And the global `selected_color` to which you gave value `np.empty([0,3])` before is untouched by that. They are not the save variables.

Which, I suspect, is not wanted. Otherwise, I wonder why this empty variable, since you never modify it anywhere, and use it only there

```py
def yellow_calib():
    AllColors[0,] = selected_color #past the last value saved ?
```

Where `selected_color` still have the only value you ever gave it.

So, that is, I suspect, your real problem: you don't know how to modify a global variable.

Solution is really simple: just declare it `global`

```py
selected_color = np.empty([0,3]) #color to be passed to the button
def click(event):
    global selected_color
    # yada yada yada...
    selected_color = [r,g,b] #saving the clicked color
```

Now, in `click`, `selected_color` is the global `selected_color`. The one which was initialized with `np.empty`. The one that `yellow_calib` will read later.

Note that you don't need `global` in `yellow_calib`. Because in `yellow_calib` you only read it.

When python encounter a expression reference to a variable (so to access it, not to modify it, For example `print(x)`), it use the local variable of this name *if it exists*,else it use the global, also if it exists, or else, it fails (it is a gross simplification. Sometimes you have more than just local and global environments, for it is enough for my point). So `print(x)` prints the local `x` if it exists, or else the global `x` if it exists, or else raise an error.

But when it encounters a l-value reference to a variable, that is something that could create the variable (for example `x=12`), then, if a local `x` exists, it modifies it, or else, it creates one. So, whatever, it doesn't affect a global x that may or may not exist.

Unless, the symbol `x` was declared `global` in the function. In which case, `x=12` alter a global `x` if it exists, or create a global `x`, if it doesn't.

It is different from some other languages, such as C, where such declaration is useless, because in C, it is unambigous: variables are all declared anyway, so there is no ambiguity whether a symbol `x` is supposed to design the local one or the global one. In C, there is no impplicit declaration of variables. But in Python, since `x=12` both affects, and create the variable, an explicit way to say if you meant to create it locally or globally is needed. By default it is local. Unless you say otherwise with declarations such as `global` or `nonlocal`

So, when you want a function to modify global variable x, you need in the declaration `global x` inside that function. When you want a function to just use (without modification) a global variable x, you just need to not create it locally (for example with `x=12`).

Last remark: modifying a variable is modifying what the symbol is associated to.
For example
`x[0]=12` doesn't count as "modifying x".

So if a global array x exists, and in a local function, where you never said `x=...` before, you say `x[0]=12`, then that code change the value of element 0 of the global array x. Because that is just using `x` not changing it (it changes `x[0]` but not `x`)

tl;dr:
You need `global selected_color` at the beginning of your `click` function.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I understood it and changed my variable selected_color to global but it didn't give me the desired result. Could you check my question, I just edited. @chrslg